# Contact Form Not Working (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form on a page that should send the details/message to an email address. You can view it here (it's in the footer): http://tedsrestaurant.com/index-working.html

HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" class="row style1" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="number" type="text" id="number" placeholder="Your number" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your e-mail" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
        <textarea name="message" rows="4" class="h130" id="message" placeholder="Write your message..." required></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="col-md-9"><p>* When booking the <strong>Food Truck</strong>, please write date, time and number of guests into your message.</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right">
        <input class="submit btn" type="submit" value="Send a message" />
        <input class="modal btn hidden" type="button" value="Send a message" name="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBox" />
    </div>

    <!-- Modal window -->
    <div class="modal fade bs-modal-md" id="modalBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact form</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the PHP is:

```
<?php

//******** Email settings ********//
//your email
$email_to = "myemail@gmail.com";
//subject of email
$email_subject = "This is a message";
//message after success send mail
$email_send = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
<strong>Contact form was sent successfully.</strong>
<br/>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</div>";

if($_POST) {
    //******** Email data ********//
    $cust_name = $_POST['name'];
    $cust_number = $_POST['number'];
    $cust_email = $_POST['email'];
    $cust_message = $_POST['message'];

    $header = "From:" . $cust_email . "\r\n";
    $header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' ."\r\n";
    $header .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $body  = "<strong>Customer email:</strong> " . $cust_email . "<br/>";
    $body .= "<strong>Customer number:</strong> " . $cust_number . "<br/>";
    $body .= "<strong>Customer name:</strong> " . $cust_name . "<br/>";
    $body .= "<strong>Message:</strong> " . $cust_message;

    if($cust_name && $cust_number && $cust_email && mail($email_to, $email_subject, $body, $header)) {
        echo $email_send;
        echo '<script>$("#contact-form").each(function(){
                    this.reset();
                });
              </script>';
    } else {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'><strong>Error sending mail. Please fill the contact form correctly or contact website administrator.</strong></div>";
    }

}
```

Does everything look correct? FYI the PHP on the site has a real email address, not myemail@gmail.com. Once I hit the submit button I am taken to the same page, but nothing ever comes to my e-mail.

Comment: did you get any eroror..???

Comment: `action="#"`?. Also change `if($_POST) {` to `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")`.

Comment: I should of checked this before, but it works fine in Chrome and in Safari, but not in Firefox, which I've been using. This seems odd to me though.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output that you receive? An email_sent or error message?

If you get neither which I guess is the case, you should be using
`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")` in place of `if($_POST)` to check if the request type is POST and further proceed.

Comment: The original code works fine in Chrome and Safari, as does the replacement code that you mentioned, but neither work correctly in Firefox for some reason. No pop-up comes up when I hit submit in Firefox. I've cleared my cache a bunch of times - no luck.

Comment: The pop-up doesnt show with firefox, but do you still receive a mail?

Comment: No, I receive nothing when the form is filled out in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org).

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
  ->setUsername('your username')
  ->setPassword('your password')
  ;

/*
You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:

// Sendmail
$transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

// Mail
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
*/

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```